# D3.ScaleTime on repeated arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this JavaScript code, that uses D3.scaleTime to make a x-axis with datetime values. It works just fine for series[0], but my issue is that I have multiple series that might have slightly differen date ranges, so I need ScaleTime to look at all dates across the values in all series.

```
var x = d3
        .scaleTime()
        .domain(
          d3.extent(this.series[0].values, function(d) {
            return d.date;
          })
        )
        .range([0, width]);
```

I have tried to use D3.merge, but I can't figure out how to merge values across any number of series.

Answer (score 0):

I came to think of c#/LINQ SelectMany, and that gave me the answer after a bit of googling:

this.series.map(a => a.values).flat()